# ADO.Entity updating a single field of one record without retrieving the whole record

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, field, updating

What is the best practise for updating a single field for one record (with specific ID) using ADO.Entity?
As far as I know, you have to retrieve the whole object by id, update the property and call SaveChanges:

```
int id = ...;
var db = new MyEntities();
var o = (from mo in db.myObject
         where mo.id = idObject
         select mo).First();
o.MyProperty = "some value";
db.SaveChanges();
```

But it seems a little bit overhead having to retrieve the whole object, since I don't care for the values of the record because I just want to set a property, regardless of the values.

Another option would be to create a stored procedure for this purpose...

Comment: Why do you think retrieving the whole record is a problem? That's what db systems are meant to do. If the record is waaaayy too large (contains multiple BLOBs, etc), then you should re-do your schema.

Comment: I don't agree that this is not a problem, because if it is behaviour that is being done thousands of times during the application's work it is an overhead. There is just no sense in fetching data you don't use, regardless of the size.

Comment: See Prof Donald Knuth, "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the root of all evil**" [Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization)

Comment: Well, I'm still not convinced that this is someting that should be accepted as a good practice, but since there is no better solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: `What is the best practise for updating a single field for one record (with specific ID) using ADO.Entity?`

Answer: Best practice is to retrieve the entire record, update one or more fields, and then store the record. -- Just as you're doing.